# Hanging indent in headings

Tags: sectioning, indentation

Good Evening,

as I am new to this whole Tex thing, making bigger adjustments to the presets still poses a problem. Basically, I want to change the setting for the headings, so they look like this:

[image]

I dont know how to align the name of the heading with the text below and how to add an indent to the heading: I don't even know how to approach this. Gooogle didn't exactly deliver.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: While Google didn't deliver, could you deliver? That is, provide us with some frame of reference in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option for the standard classes, using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newlength\TitleOverhang
\setlength\TitleOverhang{1.5cm}

\newcommand\Overhang[1]{%
  \llap{\makebox[\TitleOverhang][l]{#1}}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\Overhang{\thesection}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\Overhang{\thesubsection}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\Overhang{\thesubsubsection}}{0em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Changinf the value for `\TitleOverhang` (default=`1.5cm`), you can easily control the distance from the numbers to the left margin. I only provided code down to `\subsubsection`; for lower sectional units you could use

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\Overhang{\theparagraph}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\Overhang{\thesubparagraph}}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} 
  {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.